# SOAP XML to Array

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

Been struggling with trying to parse the following XML via PHP any help would be greatly appreciated.  NOTE: I have tried several suggestions from SO already.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns4:getBrandResponse xmlns:ns4="{{LINK}}" xmlns:c="{{LINK}}/common" xmlns:l="{{LINK}}">
<ns4:brandGroups>
<ns4:brandGroup>
<ns4:productGroup>{{GROUP NAME}}</ns4:productGroup>
<ns4:brands>
<ns4:brand>
<ns4:name>{{NAME}}</ns4:name>
<ns4:brandId>{{ID}}</ns4:brandId>
<ns4:brandLogo>
{{BRAND LOGO}}
</ns4:brandLogo>
</ns4:brand>
</ns4:brands>
</ns4:brandGroup>
</ns4:brandGroups>
</ns4:getBrandResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sorry.. should elaborate further... looking to parse an array of "brand" ->"names"  names.

Comment: Do you use the PHP SoapClient?

Comment: Actually this is a response from an XML post via CURL to the SOAP client.  Just need to parse the the XML data received to an array and then to strings.

Comment: Please elaborate by adding relevant code portions you tried, the output you're trying to achieve, and the encountered errors if any.

Comment: Right so just looking to parse the above XML to an array.  The brand->name (s) via a foreach loop would be ideal.  I think any code i've used previously is probably irrelevant as it was not producing the result desired.

Comment: The XML example is not valid (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to rid the namespace tag via str_replace and tinker with the code (a lot of manipulation) but works.

```
$data = file_get_contents('{{FILE / XML URL}}');
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p,$data,$vals,$index);
xml_parser_free($p);

$brands = $vals;

foreach($vals as $key => $value){

  foreach($value as $k => $val){

    if($val == 'NAME'){
        foreach($value as $c=>$v){
            if($c == 'value'){
                print $v;
            }
        }
    }

  }

}
```